# Templates specialization partial, full etc and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone let me know what is the difference between class template full specialization, partial specialization? What are the inhertance rules for template classes i.e could a specialized class be derived from a generic class etc?
A code would really help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question** Can anyone let me know what is the difference between class template full specialization, partial specialization?

**Answer** Full specialization means all the template parameters have been explicitly specified. Partial specialization means one or more but not all template parameters have been explicitly specified.

Example class template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct A
{
   A() { std::cout << "Came to A<T1, T2>::A()\n"; } 
};
```

Example of partial specialization.

```
template <typename T1> struct A<T1, int>
{
   A() { std::cout << "Came to A<T1, int>::A()\n"; } 
};
```

Example of fulll specialization.

```
template <> struct A<int, int>
{
   A() { std::cout << "Came to A<int, int>::A()\n"; } 
};

int main()
{
   A<char, float> a1;
   A<double, int> a2;
   A<int, int> a3;
}
```

When you run the program, you should get the following output:

```
Came to A<T1, T2>::A()
Came to A<T1, int>::A()
Came to A<int, int>::A()
```

**Question** What are the inheritance rules for template classes i.e could a specialized class be derived from a generic class etc?

**Answer** Inheritance rules for class templates, specialized or not, are same as for regular classes.

In the above example, you could derive `A<T1, T2>`, `A<T1, int>`, and `A<int, int>` derive from any class that you wish to. In turn, they could be base classes for any class too.

Since there are no specific rules for inheritance of classes involving class templates, any example would be superfluous. However, if it helps, you could do the following:

```
struct B
{
};

template <typename T1> struct A<T1, int> : public B
{
   A() { std::cout << "Came to A<T1, int>::A()\n"; } 
};
```

You could also do the following:

```
template <typename T1> struct C : public A<T1, int>
{
   C() { std::cout << "Came to C<T1>::C()\n"; } 
};

template <typename T1> struct D : public A<T1, T1*>
{
   D() { std::cout << "Came to D<T1>::D()\n"; } 
};
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I debated ignoring the question but relented since the goal of SO is to be a repository of all answers to programming questions.

Comment: _'the goal of SO is to be a repository of all answers to programming questions'_ Tough task! Good luck ;) ... (I like most of your answers BTW)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the compliment :)